# How do Sencha Touch controllers differ to ASP.NET MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sencha-touch

With ASP.NET MVC controllers, the controller itself responds with requests from the client to rebuild the view and/or supply data.

However, I'm trying to understand how a view relates to a Sencha Touch controller.  I've not seen anywhere how a controller actually creates the views. Am I missing something?

How does this compare with ASP.NET MVC controllers?

**Update**
An update to my original query since some investigation.  It seems that all controllers are loaded in by the app, and the controller itself has no knowledge of any particular view it refers to. It seems to listen to an event from any control on any view. So a controller could in effect respond to events from 2 completely different views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define what controls the Controller listens too in the "config>control" section, you uses a css like selector language to select the control, eg:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        control: {
            'button': { tap: 'onButtonTap' },
            '#superButton': { tap: 'onSuperTap' }, //select by ID
            '#SpecificView textarea': {change: 'onChange'} // all textareas in the id:View
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Having more experience now of using the controllers I think Sencha Touch controllers are all instantiated in the background and listen for changes on the views. ASP.NET MVC's controllers are invoked once a request from a view hits an endpoint on a route which maps to the controller for handling the request.